# In a Jupyter notebook how do I get syntax highlighting for javascript magic cells?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image: Javascript Magic Cell in Jupyter Notebook]

When I run a cell in my local notebook I see the above. How do I get Jupyter to apply syntax highlighting to these cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for SQL when placed in ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js with notebook 5.x:

```
require(['notebook/js/codecell'], function(codecell) {
  codecell.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes['magic_text/x-mssql'] = {'reg':[/^%%sql/]} ;
  Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', function(){
  Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().map(function(cell){
      if (cell.cell_type == 'code'){ cell.auto_highlight(); } }) ;
  });
});
```

Comment: I've removed the SQL specific stuff as an edit, and it works! Apparently JS highlighting is available "out of the box."

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript version:

```js
%%js

require(['notebook/js/codecell'], (codecell) => {
  codecell.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes.magic_javascript = 
      {reg: [/^%%(?:js|javascript|script node)/]}
  Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', () => {
    Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().map((cell) => {
      if (cell.cell_type == 'code'){
          cell.auto_highlight()
      }})
    })
})
```